# AutoResetEvent number of waiting threads .net 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

I am using AutoResetEvent.
I just need to know is it possible to get number of waiting threads?

```
if (WaitHandler.Reset())
{
     if (WaitHandler.WaitOne(WaitMilliseconds))
     {
         // do something after WaitHandler.Set()  
     }
}
```

I need to know how many threads are currently waiting in WaitOne(). And is it possible to limit them, like 10 threads max - all other threads throw back? If not - how to limit it?

Comment: Are you looking for [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0) or [Semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0) class?

Comment: @Steeeve Semaphore looks good in this case. I`ll check. Thanks

Comment: @Steeeve no, I am searching something different. Semaphore limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently. But I need to block all threads (max 10) untill something happened in another thread(and method)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, I found it at https://kmyr.dev/post/limiting-the-number-of-threads

```
internal sealed class ThreadManager
{
private readonly WaitHandle[] _syncObjects;

public ThreadManager() : this(Environment.ProcessorCount)
{
}

public ThreadManager(int maxThreads)
{
    MaxThreads = maxThreads;

    _syncObjects = new WaitHandle[maxThreads];
    for (var i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
    {
        _syncObjects[i] = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    }
}

public int MaxThreads { get; private set; }

public bool StartTask(Action action, bool wait)
{
    var timeout = wait ? Timeout.Infinite : 0;
    var freeIndex = WaitHandle.WaitAny(_syncObjects, timeout);
    if (freeIndex == WaitHandle.WaitTimeout)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        state =>
            {
                action();
                ((AutoResetEvent)state).Set();
            },
        _syncObjects[freeIndex]);

    return true;
}
}
```